# Android SQLiteException "no such table"while compiling: INSERT INTO table

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

The code is giving no such table exception. I read almost all questions
about this exception, did all what it was said. but still it doesn't work.
I couldn't find what the problem is. is there any one who can help me?

```
public class Butcegiris extends Activity {
    EditText bakici, krediAraba, krediOgrenim, krediTatil, faturaElektrik;
    EditText faturaSu, faturaInternet, aidat, kaskoSigorta;
    Spinner yillar,aylar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.butcegiris);

        bakici = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBakici);
        krediAraba = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextKrediAraba);
        krediOgrenim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOgrenimKredisi);
        krediTatil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTatilKredisi);
        faturaElektrik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFaturaElektrik);
        faturaSu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFaturaSu);
        faturaInternet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFaturaInternet);
        aidat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAidat);
        kaskoSigorta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextKaskoSigorta);
        yillar=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerYillar);
        aylar=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAylar);

        Button ileri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIleri);
        ileri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean didItWork=true;
                try {
                    int bakicisql = Integer.valueOf(bakici.getText().toString());
                    int krediArabasql = Integer.valueOf(krediAraba.getText()
                            .toString());
                    int krediOgrenimsql = Integer.valueOf(krediOgrenim.getText()
                            .toString());
                    int krediTatilsql = Integer.valueOf(krediTatil.getText()
                            .toString());
                    int faturaElektriksql = Integer.valueOf(faturaElektrik
                            .getText().toString());
                    int faturaSusql = Integer
                            .valueOf(faturaSu.getText().toString());
                    int faturaInternetsql = Integer.valueOf(faturaInternet
                            .getText().toString());
                    int aidatsql = Integer.valueOf(aidat.getText().toString());
                    int kaskoSigortasql = Integer.valueOf(kaskoSigorta.getText()
                            .toString());
                    String yil=yillar.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String ay= aylar.getSelectedItem().toString();


                    TemporaryDatabase entry = new TemporaryDatabase(Butcegiris.this);

                    entry.open();

                    entry.createEntryGiris(yil,ay,bakicisql, krediArabasql, krediOgrenimsql,
                            krediTatilsql, faturaElektriksql, faturaSusql,
                            faturaInternetsql, aidatsql, kaskoSigortasql);

                    entry.close();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Butcegiris.this, Butcehesapla.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    didItWork=false;
                } finally {

                    if(didItWork){

                        Toast.makeText(Butcegiris.this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.butcegiris_xml, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.ikinciSayfa:

            Intent intent = new Intent(Butcegiris.this, Butcehesapla.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

TemporaryDatabase class

```
    public class TemporaryDatabase 

{

    public static final String TAG = DbHelperTemporary.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_NAME = "butcedb.sql";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.deitel.btc/assets/";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "harcamalar";

    public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID;// Special for id
    public static final String C_YIL = "spinnerYillar";
    public static final String C_AY = "spinnerAylar";
    public static final String C_BAKICI = "editTextBakici";
    public static final String C_KREDIARABA = "editTextKrediAraba";
    public static final String C_KREDIOGRENIM = "editTextKrediOgrenim";
    public static final String C_KREDITATIL = "editTextKrediTatil";
    public static final String C_FATURAELEKTRIK = "editTextFaturaElektrik";
    public static final String C_FATURASU = "editTextFaturaSu";
    public static final String C_FATURAINTERNET = "editTextFaturaInternet";
    public static final String C_AIDAT = "editTextAidat";
    public static final String C_KASKOSIGORTA = "editTextKaskoSigorta";

    public static final String C_DIGERTAKSITLER = "editTextDigerTaksitler";
    public static final String C_DIGER = "editTextDiger";
    public static final String C_MAASSELO = "editTextMaasSelo";
    public static final String C_MAASHILAL = "editTextMaasHilal";
    public static final String C_DIGERGELIRLER = "editTextDigerGelirler";
    public static final String C_TOPLAMHARCAMA = "editTextToplamHarcama";
    public static final String C_TOPLAMGELIR = "editTextToplamGelir";
    public static final String C_ELDEKALAN = "editTextEldeKalan";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE ıf not exists harcamalar (C_ID int primary key autoincrement," +
            "C_YIL int,C_AY TEXT,C_BAKICI int,C_KREDIARABA int,C_KREDIOGRENIM int,C_KREDITATIL int," +
            "C_FATURAELEKTRIK int,C_FATURASU int,C_FATURAINTERNET int,C_AIDAT int,C_KASKOSIGORTA int," +
            "C_DIGERTAKSITLER int,C_DIGER int,C_MAASSELO int,C_MAASHILAL int,C_DIGERGELIRLER int," +
            "C_TOPLAMHARCAMA int,C_TOPLAMGELIR int, C_ELDEKALAN int);";


    private DbHelperTemporary dbHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelperTemporary extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        public DbHelperTemporary(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try {

                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: " + CREATE_TABLE);
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DB_TABLE);
            Log.w(TAG, "onUpdate drop table " + DB_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public TemporaryDatabase(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;

    }
    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public  void open() throws NumberFormatException {

        try {
            dbHelper = new DbHelperTemporary(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Couldn't open database"+DB_NAME);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {

        dbHelper.close();
        ourDatabase.close();
    }

    public long createEntryGiris(String yilsql, String aysql, int bakicisql,
            int krediArabasql, int krediOgrenimsql, int krediTatilsql,
            int faturaElektriksql, int faturaSusql, int faturaInternetsql,
            int aidatsql, int kaskoSigortasql) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(C_YIL, yilsql);
        cv.put(C_AY, aysql);
        cv.put(C_BAKICI, bakicisql);
        cv.put(C_KREDIARABA, krediArabasql);
        cv.put(C_KREDIOGRENIM, krediOgrenimsql);
        cv.put(C_KREDITATIL, krediTatilsql);
        cv.put(C_FATURAELEKTRIK, faturaElektriksql);
        cv.put(C_FATURASU, faturaSusql);
        cv.put(C_FATURAINTERNET, faturaInternetsql);
        cv.put(C_AIDAT, aidatsql);
        cv.put(C_KASKOSIGORTA, kaskoSigortasql);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String[] getData() {

        String[] columns = new String[] { C_YIL, C_AY, C_BAKICI, C_KREDIARABA,
                C_KREDIOGRENIM, C_KREDITATIL, C_FATURAELEKTRIK, C_FATURASU,
                C_FATURAINTERNET, C_AIDAT, C_KASKOSIGORTA };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        String[] result = new String[10];

        //int i_yil = c.getColumnIndex(C_YIL);
        //int i_ay = c.getColumnIndex(C_AY);
        int i_bakici = c.getColumnIndex(C_BAKICI);
        int i_krediaraba = c.getColumnIndex(C_KREDIARABA);
        int i_krediogrenim = c.getColumnIndex(C_KREDIOGRENIM);
        int i_kreditatil = c.getColumnIndex(C_KREDITATIL);
        int i_faturaelektrik = c.getColumnIndex(C_FATURAELEKTRIK);
        int i_faturasu = c.getColumnIndex(C_FATURASU);
        int i_faturainternet = c.getColumnIndex(C_FATURAINTERNET);
        int i_aidat = c.getColumnIndex(C_AIDAT);
        int i_kaskosigorta = c.getColumnIndex(C_KASKOSIGORTA);

        if (c.moveToLast()) {
            result[0]=c.getString(i_bakici);
            result[1]=c.getString(i_krediaraba);
            result[2]=c.getString(i_krediogrenim);
            result[3]=c.getString(i_kreditatil);
            result[4]=c.getString(i_faturaelektrik);
            result[5]=c.getString(i_faturasu);
            result[6]=c.getString(i_faturainternet);
            result[7]=c.getString(i_aidat);
            result[8]=c.getString(i_kaskosigorta);


            /*result = c.getString(i_bakici) + " " + c.getString(i_krediaraba)
                    + " " + c.getString(i_krediogrenim) + " "+ c.getString(i_kreditatil) + " "+ c.getString(i_faturaelektrik) + " "
                    + c.getString(i_faturasu) + " "+ c.getString(i_faturainternet) + " "
                    + c.getString(i_aidat) + " " + c.getString(i_kaskosigorta);*/
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

And here is the xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textButtonBakici"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textBakici"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextBakici"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/altiyuzyirmibes"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

         </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textKrediAraba"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textKrediAraba"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextKrediAraba"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/besyuzdoksan"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textOgrenimKredisi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textOgrenimKredisi"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextOgrenimKredisi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/dortyuzon"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTatilKredisi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textTatilKredisi"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTatilKredisi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/yuzotuzbes"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFaturaElektrik"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textFaturaElektrik"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextFaturaElektrik"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/sifir"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFaturaSu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textFaturaSu"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextFaturaSu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/sifir"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFaturaInternet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textFaturaInternet"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextFaturaInternet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/otuz"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAidat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textAidat"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAidat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/sifir"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textKaskoSigorta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/textKaskoSigorta"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextKaskoSigorta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/ikiyuzyirmibes"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10">

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/spinnerYillar"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="3"
             android:entries="@array/Yillar"
             android:prompt="@string/promptYillar" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAylar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt"
            android:entries="@array/Aylar"
             />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonIleri"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/navigation_forward" />

        </TableRow>     

</TableLayout>
```

I know it is long but I couldn't find the problem.
Thank you very much for your help.

```
no such table: harcamalar
Error inserting spinnerYillar=2012 editTextFaturaSu=9 editTextKrediOgrenim=9 editTextAidat=9 editTextFaturaElektrik=99 editTextKaskoSigorta=9 editTextKrediAraba=9 spinnerAylar=Ocak editTextFaturaInternet=6 editTextBakici=9 editTextKrediTatil=9

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: harcamalar (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO harcamalar(spinnerYillar,editTextFaturaSu,editTextKrediOgrenim,editTextAidat,editTextFaturaElektrik,editTextKaskoSigorta,editTextKrediAraba,spinnerAylar,editTextFaturaInternet,editTextBakici,editTextKrediTatil) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
at com.deitel.btc.TemporaryDatabase.createEntryGiris(TemporaryDatabase.java:131)
at com.deitel.btc.Butcegiris$1.onClick(Butcegiris.java:69)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-19 12:27:17.976: E/SQLiteDatabase(1023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hey guy, debug your aplication for see where it is error..

Comment: I see that `DB_VERSION` is on 2, have you incremented this number since your latest changes?

Comment: yes ı change after changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of int in the CREATE_TABLE statement, you should use integer

So use

```
C_ID integer primary key autoincrement
```

Check this [doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html)

Quoted

> you must use "INTEGER" not "INT". A column of type INT PRIMARY KEY is
>   typeless just like any other

Instead of

```
CREATE TABLE ıf not exists harcamalar (C_ID int primary key autoincrement," +
            "C_YIL int,C_AY TEXT,C_BAKICI int .. so on
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE ıf not exists harcamalar (C_ID int primary key autoincrement," +
            C_YIL + "int," + C_AY + "TEXT,"+ C_BAKICI +" int .. so on
```

You need to append the value of variables rather than variable names itself

Comment: remove the catch exception on open call, by catching exceptions you are making it difficult to debug issue. Maybe there is an exception when you do open and even in Oncreate. Remove all handling of unchecked exceptions

Comment: ı did what you said and here is the last log:  E/SQLiteLog(1814): (1) table harcamalar has no column named spinnerYillar

Comment: ok. then your Create table is wrong, you are using C_YIL as the name of the column whereas it is the variable name so check the edit

Comment: you are right... it doesn't throw exception now . thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

Your CREATE_TABLE statement does not seem to be correct.

```
CREATE TABLE ıf
```

should perhaps be

```
CREATE TABLE if
```

I've been having issues using the "if not exists" expression earlier, perhaps you can try without it if my first suggestion doesn't work to try to narrow this down. You might also try to type out "integer" instead of just "int" in the sql statement. Not sure that shorthand is legal.

Comment: It might be a good idea to have a SQLite server running locally on your machine to try out queries on. Or you could try the SQLite manager plugin for Firefox which is very useful: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ Using that you can try your queries and make sure they are correct.

Comment: ı tried but. again didn't work. still saying "no such table."

Comment: Try wrapping your table creation in a try/catch, you will probably get an SQLException that you can log and see what the problem is, and if it is in the crate table statement. If you report that back I'm sure we can find the problem.

Comment: You might also need to uninstall the app before trying a fix to make sure your database is not created.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem building my application I tried everything and nothing worked. The database was just fine along with the table name.

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: (code 1) Android

**Solution:**
The only way that solved the problem was to un-install the application from the emulator:

1- Open the emulator , go to Settings
2- click on Apps
3- scroll to find your Application name
4- Double click on it
5- Force Stop
6- UnInstall it.

run your application again from android studio and try to check the database connectivity. This worked for me , good luck.